# request.get is not working inside a callback of node-cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

Hello I am writing a script to make a request to a particular url every second, but as soon as I write my code inside node-cron callback, I get **TypeError request.get is not a function**. Here is my code

```
    var request = require('request');
    var generalConfig = require('./config.js')

    var cron = require('node-cron');
    var async = require('async');

    var failures = {
        webEndManager: 0,
        userManager: 0
    }
    cron.schedule('* * * * * *', function () {

        async.parallel({
            webEndManager: function (callback) {
                request.get({
                    url: generalConfig.webEndManager
                },
                    function (error, response, body) {
                        if (response) {
                            failures.webEndManager = 0;
                            callback(null, 'success');
                        }
                        else {
                            failures.webEndManager = failures.webEndManager + 1;
                            if (failures.webEndManager == 1)
                                callback(null, 'fail');
                            else
                                callback(null, 'success');
                        }
                    });
                console.log("one 3000");
            },
            userManager: function (callback) {
                request.get({
                    url: generalConfig.userManager
                },
                    function (error, response, body) {
                        if (response) {
                            failures.webEndManager = 0;
                            callback(null, 'success');
                        }
                        else {
                            failures.webEndManager = failures.webEndManager + 1;
                            if (failures.webEndManager == 1)
                                callback(null, 'fail');
                            else
                                callback(null, 'success');
                        }
                    });
                console.log("one 5001");
            },
        }, function (err, results) {
            // results is now equals to: {one: 'abc\n', two: 'xyz\n'}
            console.log(results);
        });
    console.log('running a task every minute');

});
```

It was working fine when the async code was not inside cron callback.

Comment: Try to move `var request = require('request');` inside the cron.schedule

Comment: Thanks !! that worked, but why did that work ? I mean request was in global scope before at top, so what effect this change had on code?

Comment: Probably something related to cron package? I don't know.

Comment: the cron package can't reference global objects declared outside of it because it is meant to run as a standalone. thats why you would need to declare the request inside the cron.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @zerohero , please create an answer  so that I can accept and close this question

Comment: This doesn't happen for `cron` package. Maybe you can try that as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cron package can't reference global objects declared outside of it because it is meant to run as a standalone. thats why you would need to declare the request inside the cron.

so by moving this line:

```
var request = require('request');
```

into the cron.schedule, you are able to access it.